# print binary strings to a textfile with specific row lengths

Tags: matlab, binary, printf

Unix+matlab R2016b

I have a 1 dim table with numbers that I'd like to export to a 12-bit binary table in a text file.

```
x = [0:1:250];
a = exp(-((x*8)/350));
b = exp(-((x*8)/90));
y = a-b;
y_12bit = y*4095;
y_12bitRound = ceil(y_12bit);
y_12bitRoundBinary = de2bi(y_12bitRound,12);

fileID = fopen('expo_1.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%12s',y_12bitRoundBinary);
```

Now, y_12bitRoundBinary looks good when i print this in the console.

```
y_12bitRoundBinary =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

This looks good, but I would like the bit order to be reversed. The MSBs are towards the right and I would like a little-endian ordering. Also, I don't know if this printing actually proves that y_12bitRoundBinary is correct.

1. Are there spaces in between each bit or is this just the format of the printing function?
2. How to change the ordering?

The first lines of the data written to file expo_1.txt:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 0001 0001
0001 0000 0101 0001 0101 0100 0000 0100
0101 0000 0000 0100 0100 0101 0000 0100
0000 0001 0001 0101 0100 0100 0000 0100
0101 0101 0001 0101 0000 0101 0101 0100
0100 0000 0101 0001 0101 0101 0100 0101
```

As you see, the data is beyond recognition compared with how y_12bitRoundBinary was printed in the Matlab console.

3. Would anyone have any pointers on where my mistake is concerning the data written to file?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want as output. I get "binary" output, i.e. non-ascii characters. Is that what you want?

Comment: Please remove the sentences: "There could be some spaces inserted there for all I know" and "Also it would be optimal if it was little-endian instead of big". You should be more precise.  "little-endian" is not well defined for bits ordering in text format - give an example. Where spaces are required, and where not? How many character pet line in text file?  You wrote "output file is:"... output of what? It doesn't look like an output of your Matlab code. Make a simple example: single decimal input, and expected output.

Comment: Hint: consider using `dec2bin(y_12bitRound, 12)` instead of `de2bi(y_12bitRound,12)`.

Comment: Joergen (no Norwegian keyboard) and Rotem, I modified my post. Sorry for the unclear question. Btw. What's the difference between dec2bin and de2bi? They seem to produce the same result.

Comment: `dec2bin`returns a char array, where `de2bi` returns a vector/matrix of doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you would like to print the numbers as ASCII strings, this will work

```
x = 0:250;
a = exp(-((x*8)/350));
b = exp(-((x*8)/90));
y = a-b;

% Reduce to 12 bit precision
y_12bit = y*2^12;
y_12bitRound = floor(y_12bit);

% Convert y_12bitRound to char arrays with 12 bits precision
y_12bitCharArray = dec2bin(y_12bitRound,12);

% Convert to cell array of string
y_12bitCellArray = cellstr(y_12bitCharArray);

fileID = fopen('expo_1.txt','wt');
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n', y_12bitCellArray{:});
fclose(fileID);
```

This will print the following to the file `expo_1.txt`

```
000000000000
000011111111
000111100100
001010101111
001101100011
010000000011
010010010000
...
```

The trick is to convert the char array to a cell array of strings, which is easier to print as desired, using the `{:}` operator to expand the cell array.

Comment: Precisely what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will do. One thing though: Matlab complains about fprintf. "Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs". fprintf is supposed to have y_12bitCellArray in the argument right? skipping the cellstr step and using y_12bitCharArray in the fprintf argument returns what I want and what you have printed as the output to the expo_1.txt file.

Comment: Sorry, it does NOT produce what I want. formatting is quite wrong without the cellstr, but apparently cells cannot be used as an argument for fprintf.

Comment: Sorry for commenting before actually trying. Solved the cell argument with a for loop. If anyone else is wondering:
for x = 1 : size(x,2)
    fprintf(fileID,'%s\n', y_12bitCellArray{x}(1:end-1));
end

Comment: Actually, a problem which I just spotted now is that the LSBs are omitted from each row so that they are only 11 bits each. I tried increasing the dec2bin width but it's still the same. Any pointers?

Comment: I hope I found your eror. The reducing to 12 bit should be done by multiplying with 2^12 and then flooring

Comment: It did, thanks! but I don't understand why. the y_12bitCellArray looked good before being written to file.